IXSCAN with very large keysExamined value
Mongodb 4.4.12
I try to understand very strange performance characteristics of the query like below.
There is a unique index on the myID field of the mycoll collection having quite a large number of documents (XX millions).
db.mycoll.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      $and: [
        { 'myId': { $in: [~ 1000 constants] } } 
      ]
    }
  }
])

I may see very different performance values for queries with the same queryHash and planCacheKey pair and slightly different number of ids in $in (but still ~1000). For example:
{
  attr: {
    keysExamined: 8 000,
    docsExamined: 4 000,
    storage: {
      data: {
        bytesRead: 500 000 000
      }
    },
    durationMillis: 1 000
  }
}

{
  attr: {
    keysExamined: 350 000,
    docsExamined: 180 000,
    storage: {
      data: {
        bytesRead: 13 000 000 000
      }
    },
    durationMillis: 50 000
  }
}

It doesn't depend on if a query was replanned or not.
Update:
Query plans look the same in both cases (w/ and w/o $and in $match) like below.
...
        "optimizedPipeline" : true,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "myId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "myId",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "myId" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "myId" : [
                        "[\"id1\", \"id1\"]",
                        ...,
                        "[\"idX\", \"idX\"]"
                    ]
                }
...          

Questions:

What would be a reason for such a huge value in keysExamined (even in the better case) when not more than 1000 ids only passed to the query to check against a unique index?

Is there any chance, that the reason is in unnecessary $and inside $match, and we must run the following query instead to get better performance?


db.mycoll.aggregate([
  { $match: 
    { 'myId': { $in: [~ 1000 constants] } } 
  }
])

Thanks in advance.

Run those with explain so you can see the index bounds used.

@Joe I've updated my question with an excerpt from a query plan.

My guess would be there is a limit on the number of index ranges the planner can use.  When you test various queries with explain, look at how many index ranges are shown for each, how many ids were in the query, and how many keys were examined.

@Joe When I get explain, I see the same picture every time as described above: if XXX parameters are passed to a query, the indexBounds element contains the same XXX number of pairs of equal string constants, where each one corresponds to a particular parameter value passed. Is it possible, that indexBounds can be set somehow different at runtime because of, say, a large number of parameters?

BTW, it's strange, that I always see "nreturned":1 in the slow query log for these queries, but "nReturned" : XXX (equal to number of parameters passed) in explain. I have no idea why...
